# Confirmation this inheritence is valid

Tags: java, inheritance, relationship

I am creating a CustomerList Class, currently:

```
package somestuff;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomerList {

    ArrayList<Customer> custList;

}
```

I want it to extend ArrayList; would this be a valid "is-a" relationship (CustomerList is an ArrayList)?

Edit: Apologies, I haven't made this post too clear. My plan is to have this as part of a JSP website; I'd query a database and use Customer and CustomerList to store the results. My theory is that it will make things easier if I wanted to change the order of how they're outputted.

Comment: no, this customer list has-a array list

Comment: If this is homework, please add the homework tag.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is a `has-a` relationship. `is-a` will be if you extend (class) or implement (interface).

Wouldn't it be simpler to just use `ArrayList<Customer>` when needed?

Comment: There are probably operations you'd want on a `CustomerList` in addition to those provided by `ArrayList<Customer>`. Conversely, there are likely operations in `ArrayList<Customer>` you don't particularly want. It's difficult to know given the information why a `List` should be preferable to a `Set`, or why it specifically needs to be this particular implementation.

Comment: True, but I have seen no such operations in the OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truly extend `ArrayList`, the proper method is:

```
public class CustomerList extends ArrayList<Customer> {

    // ... add/override methods here

}
```

What kind of functionality do you want to add?

Comment: My plan was to have this as part of a JSP website; I'd query a database and use Customer and CustomerList to store the results. My theory is that it will make things easier if I wanted to change the order of how they're outputted.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this into an `is-a` relationship by either extending (as Binyamin Sharet said) or by extending the `java.util.List` interface and delegating the execution of the methods to `custList` (look up Joshua Bloch).

Answer (score 0):

You may also use delegation.

```
class Customer{}
class CustomerList extends AbstractList<Customer>{

    private final List<Customer> customers;
    public CustomerList(List<Customer> customers){
        this.customers = customers;
    }
    @Override
    public Customer get(int index) {
        return customers.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return customers.size();
    }

    //Override more methods as needed
}
```

It depends what you want to do.
However, using composition is simpler and nicer.